# Не получается управлять ProgressBar'ом из DLL

Tags: delphi, dll, progress-bar, delphi-xe, inno-setup

Как управлять ProgressBar'ом из **DLL**, написанной на **DX (Delphi 10 Seattle)**, в **Inno Setup (ANSI)**? Если делаю тоже самое, создав приложение на **DX**, то все нормально импортируется и отображается.

Привожу листинг кода:

**Код DLL DX:**

```
function Process(Pb: TProgressBar): Integer; stdcall;
var
 I: integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to 1000 do
  begin
    Pb.Position := I;
    Pb.Update;
    Sleep(10);
  end;
end;

Exports
  Process;
```

**Код Inno Setup (ANSI):**

```
function Count(Progr: TNewProgressBar): integer; external 'Process@files:CallC.dll stdcall delayload';

procedure NewButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   Count(NewProgressBar1);
end;
```

При вызове в ответ получаю **Acces Violation**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может у кого есть правильное решение?

**Код создания страницы:**

```
[Code]
var
  NewButton1: TNewButton;
  NewProgressBar1: TNewProgressBar;

procedure NewButton1Click(Sender: TObject); forward;

procedure RedesignWizardForm;
begin
  { NewButton1 }
  NewButton1 := TNewButton.Create(WizardForm);
  with NewButton1 do
  begin
    Parent := WizardForm;
    Left := ScaleX(152);
    Top := ScaleY(327);
    Width := ScaleX(57);
    Height := ScaleY(26);
    Caption := 'Клик';
    OnClick := @NewButton1Click;
  end;

  NewProgressBar1 := TNewProgressBar.Create(WizardForm);
  with NewProgressBar1 do
  begin
    Parent := WizardForm;
    Left := ScaleX(8);
    Top := ScaleY(328);
    Width := ScaleX(137);
    Height := ScaleY(25);
    Max := 1000;
  end;

  NewButton1.TabOrder := 5;
  NewProgressBar1.TabOrder := 6;
end;

function Count(Progr: TNewProgressBar): integer; external 'Process@files:CallProc.dll stdcall delayload';

procedure NewButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   Count(NewProgressBar1);
end;
```

**А вот так вот это выглядит:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: TProgressBar в Delphi 10 и TNewProgressBar в Inno Setup - разные вещи.

Comment: А вы не могли бы показать, как правильно нужно передавать функцию?

Comment: Ограничьтесь простыми типами для параметров и возвращаемых значений.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, о чем вы? По-моему тут и так все проще некуда.

Comment: Что такое TProgressBar и TNewProgressBar - контролы? Почему Вы считаете, что у них хотя бы идентичное представление в памяти? Любая операция с памятью через границу Exe/Dll - с Delphi'евскими строками этого практически невозможно избежать - с большой вероятностью приведет к Access Violation. Почитайте про SharedMem, на моей памяти, каждый новый Dll проект, содержал в dpr файле комментарий, посвященый этому вопросу.

Comment: Да, я читал, указывал его как и было сказано первой строчкой, но эффект от этого не поменялся, если Вы знаете как правильно нужно передавать покажите пожалуйста, если не трудно.

Comment: Что такое TProgressBar и TNewProgressBar?

Comment: TProgressBar и TNewProgressBar - это контрол, что в Inno Setup что в Delphi X. Только в Inno Setup он TWinControl, но я не думаю что различие имен классов, может повлиять на вызов.

Comment: TWinControl означает, что это абстрактный класс, который Вам следует имплементировать собственным классом. То есть создать и передать Handle его окна в Inno Setup.

Comment: Охо-хо :(. Это два совершенно разных класса (даже не преобразуемые один в другой) с совершенно разными представлениями в памяти и с совершенно разными таблицами виртуальных методов (если это Вам что-нибудь говорит). То, что Вы делаете, работать не может.

Comment: Ну вот, как приятно поговорить с умными людьми, поэтому и написал сюда, у меня к Вам очень большая просьба показать как правильно передавать **HANDLE**. Ну выручите ребят а?

Answer (score 2):

```
function CreateOutputProgressPage(const ACaption, ADescription: String): TOutputProgressWizardPage;
```

Чтобы отображать или изменять состояние прогресс-бара, вызывайте метод `SetProgress`. `SetProgress` принимает 2 параметра `integer`: первый определяет позицию прогресс-бара (начиная с 0), второй определяет максимум. Если второй параметр равен 0, прогресс-бар не отображается (скрыт).

Найдено [здесь](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createoutputprogresspage).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35779/discussion-on-answer-by-vanyamba-electronics----progressbar).

Answer (score 2):

Передавайте в DLL вместо контрола указатель на функцию (stdcall) из Inno Setup с параметром `integer`, которую DLL будет вызывать в цикле. А функция Inno Setup будет устанавливать свойство `NewProgressBar1.Position` (или что там у него) и вызывать `NewProgressBar1.Update;`.

Inno Setup:

```
function SetProgressPosition(aPosition: integer): integer;
begin
  NewProgressBar1.Position := aPosition;
  NewProgressBar1.Update;
  result := 0;
end;

function Count(aCallback: function(aPosition: integer): integer): integer; external 'Process@files:CallProc.dll stdcall delayload';

procedure NewButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   Count(@SetProgressPosition);
end;
```

DLL:

```
type
  TSetProgressPosition = function(aPosition: integer): integer;

function Process(aCallback: TSetProgressPosition): Integer; stdcall;
var
 I: integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to 1000 do
  begin
    aCallback(I);
    Sleep(10);
  end;
end;

Exports
  Process;
```